# more than 10 viewports on compiz on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiz, viewports

Is there any limit of how many workspaces compiz can goto using "Switch to viewport"? If so, can this limit be changed or worked around?

I have configured 12 viewports, (4 * 3 under desktop size) on ubuntu 14.04. I've mapped all 12 viewports to key commands in compiz under
"Viewport switcher" -> "Goto specific viewport"
mapping the switch to control, alt and another letter on the keyboard as such:

- control+alt+q: "Switch to viewport 1"
- control+alt+w: "Switch to viewport 2"
- control+alt+e: "Switch to viewport 3"
- control+alt+r: "Switch to viewport 4"
- control+alt+a: "Switch to viewport 5"
- control+alt+s: "Switch to viewport 6"
- control+alt+d: "Switch to viewport 7"
- control+alt+f: "Switch to viewport 8"
- control+alt+z: "Switch to viewport 9"
- control+alt+x: "Switch to viewport 10"
- control+alt+c: "Switch to viewport 11"
- control+alt+v: "Switch to viewport 12"

The first 10 works, "Switch to viewport 11" and "Switch to viewport 12" does not work.

Using the workspace switcher, however, I can click on the last 2 workspaces and go to them that way. So it seemes to be supported.

I can also move windows to all 12 workspaces using a mapping I've made under
Window manager -> Put -> Bindings -> Put on arbirtrary viewport -> "Put on viewport X" using 12 similar key commands (shift+alt instead of control+alt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a work around that allows me to go to the last 2 desktops. And that is to use the wmctrl command and map them using
general -> commands -> command line 1 and 2.

Desktop 11:

```
wmctrl -o 7680,2400
```

Desktop 12:

```
wmctrl -o 11520,2400
```

I have a screen resolution of 3840x1200 (since i use 2 monitors with 1920x1200 resolution)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any limit of how many workspaces compiz can goto using "Switch to viewport"?

[Compiz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager/ConfiguringCompiz) has a limit on the amount of viewports:

> Increasing the Number of 'ViewPorts'
>
> Under `apps>compiz>general>screen0>options`, change the value of the size key. The minimal (and default) value is 4, the maximal value is 32.
>
> If so, can this limit be changed or worked around?

You will not be able to go over 32. But that number is a lot higher than 10.

I would consider your problem a bug in probably unity.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply.Using the gconf-editor, I only have hsize and vsize there. And they're both set to 2. I tried setting them to hsize=4 and vsize to 3 but that did not change anything.